# Date is not accurate while saving parseObject

Tags: android, parse-platform

Hello I am developing an application using parse.When I save an object there are some fields updated autamatically like createdAt and updatedAt which saves the date and time at which the object was created or updated.When I am creating or updating a parse object I get the date and time not the date of my computer and my computer is having a correct date and time still the createdAt and updatedAt fields are not containing the accurate values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All dates stored on Parse are stored in UTC. so make sure you convert them to correct time zone

```
     Date p =pObject.getCreatedAt();
     SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
     p = sdf.parse(sdf.format(p));
     sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"));
     System.out.println(sdf.format(p));
```

Comment: How to convert it into timezone for india  GMT+5.30 ?

Comment: Hey sorry but its not working coz of typecast problem in DateFormat and SimpleDateFormat

Comment: I also tried this.I am getting date using  Date p =pObject.getDate("createdAt");
Now I tried your answer on p   but its not working

Answer (score 1):

Parse use GMT+00 timezone for Date fields

Comment: Ok how can I get standard time for India from this time?